# Keep the Ref Cursor records as it is?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please find the scenario below.

The view `al_name_vw` has

```
No    Name

1     Murugan
2     xxxxx
3     yyyyy
4     bbbbb
5     aaaaa
```

i already get the data from the ref cursor like below.

```
open p_ref_name for
 select  anv.no,
         anv.Name
 from    al_name_vw anv 
order by anv.name;
```

So i m getting the result as

```
No    Name

5     aaaaa
4     bbbbb
1     Murugan
2     xxxxx
3     yyyyy
```

Now i need to modify the logic to retrieve the records like below.

```
No    Name

5     aaaaa
4     bbbbb
2     xxxxx
3     yyyyy
1     Murugan
```

Comment: and what is the logic? initcap goes last?

Answer (score 0):

```
select anv.no,
       anv.Name
  from al_name_vw anv 
 order by case when substr(anv.Name,1,1) = lower(substr(anv.Name,1,1)) --ensures names starting
                    then 1                                             --with lowercase come first
                    else 2
                end,
          anv.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
WITH
     T AS
     ( SELECT 1 NO, 'Murugan' NAME FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 2, 'xxxxx' FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT 3, 'yyyyy' FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT 4, 'bbbbb' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 5, 'aaaaa' FROM DUAL
     )
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY
     TRANSLATE (NAME, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

Your query,

```
OPEN p_ref_name FOR
 SELECT  anv.NO,
         anv.NAME
 FROM    al_name_vw anv 
ORDER BY 
     TRANSLATE (NAME, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

Answer (score 0):

With your result set i guess you need name with repeating same characters first followed by non repeating. Use the below query for it. If it is notwhat you want, update your question with logic behind your question.

```
 select  anv.no,
     anv.Name
  from  (select  no,
     Name, case when regexp_like(Name,'^(.)\1+$') then 1 else 2 end rn
  from    al_name_vw ) anv
  order by rn
```